# siunitx and hvmath fonts: strange mixing with cm fonts

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I'm using hvmath, [a proprietary font by micropress](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/hvmath/hvmain.htm). The [`hvmaths` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/hvmath) is openly available: as far as I understand, its aim is to replace text and math fonts with the ones provided by `hvmath` font family.

With `siunitx`, I get strange results when using `\num` or `\SI`: default computer modern font are displayed instead of `hvmath` font (notice the difference between `\celsius` and `\joule`: puzzling!).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hvmaths}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
123, $123$, \num{123}, $\num{123}$. 12°C, $\SI{12}{\celsius}$, 1J, $\SI{1}{\joule}$.
\end{document}
```

I know it may be difficult to reproduce since hvmath fonts cannot be downloaded for free, but I'd really like to know how to fix it.

***Edit***

A bit more information with my log file.

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+hvr on input line 7.
 (/home/christophe/texmf/tex/latex/hvmaths/ot1hvr.fd
File: ot1hvr.fd 2001/05/18 v1.5 LaTeX HV Roman font definition (OT1 encoding)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+hvm on input line 7.

(/home/christophe/texmf/tex/latex/hvmaths/omlhvm.fd
File: omlhvm.fd 2001/05/18 v1.5 LaTeX HV math font definition (OML encoding)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+hvsy on input line 7.

(/home/christophe/texmf/tex/latex/hvmaths/omshvsy.fd
File: omshvsy.fd 2001/05/18 v1.5 LaTeX HV math symbol font definition (OMS enco
ding)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+hvex on input line 7.

(/home/christophe/texmf/tex/latex/hvmaths/omxhvex.fd
File: omxhvex.fd 2001/05/18 v1.5 LaTeX HV math extended symbol font definition 
(OMX encoding)
)
\c__siunitx_mathtt_int=\count136
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+hvr on input line 8.

(/home/christophe/texmf/tex/latex/hvmaths/ts1hvr.fd
File: ts1hvr.fd 2001/05/18 v1.5 LaTeX HV text symbol font definition (TS1 encod
ing)
) [1

{/home/christophe/.texlive2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (
./u.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10125 strings out of 493107
 220530 string characters out of 6134839
 212588 words of memory out of 9000000
 13529 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 20063 words of font info for 41 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,7n,56p,10384b,784s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr
/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb></home
/christophe/texmf/fonts/type1/micropress-inc/hvmaths/hvsy10.pfb></home/christop
he/texmf/fonts/type1/micropress-inc/hvmaths/mphv.pfb>
```

***EDIT 2*** (thanks to cfr's comment)

Know, if I setup `siunitx` with the `math-rm` option, I get:

[image]

It is better but still not what I'm expecting: the last J (from \joule) is in italics.

By the way, this must me linked:

```
\documentclass[convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hvmaths}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
$\ce{C_{\alpha}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

since, with `\usepackage{lmodern}` instead of `\usepackage{hvmaths}`, I get:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}`?

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes. I get the exact same thing.

Comment: Does it help if you load the package `textcomp`? Also, make sure you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @cfr The image was generated by the exact same file as above (ie with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{textcomp}`).

Comment: Note that a fair comparison for the Celsius symbol would be with `\textcelsius` rather than `C`. And you should make sure that the degree is actually typesetting `\textdegree`.

Comment: Also, the image you've posted is certainly not replacing fonts with Computer Modern Roman but probably Computer Modern Sans. Try passing `siunitx` the `math-rm` option i.e. tell it to use *roman* for maths rather than letting it do automatic detection. I think the font package is not set up quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround, but it is still unclear why it works.

`hvmaths.sty` does not define a `\mathrm` of a `mathsf` alphabet, so I need to define it.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hvmaths}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{OT1}{hvr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{hvr}{m}{n}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
OK: $\mathrm{J} = \mathsf{J}$.

\sisetup{math-rm = \mathsf}
\verb+\sisetup{math-rm = \mathsf}+ OK: 123, $123$, \num{123}, $\num{123}$. 12°C, $\SI{12}{\celsius}$, 1J, $\SI{1}{\joule}$.

\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}
\verb+\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}+ OK: 123, $123$, \num{123}, $\num{123}$. 12°C, $\SI{12}{\celsius}$, 1J, $\SI{1}{\joule}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

For some reason (?), `math-rm = \mathrm` option must be set after `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hvmaths}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{OT1}{hvr}{m}{n}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}
\begin{document}
\verb+\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}+ in preamble NO

123, $123$, \num{123}, $\num{123}$. 12°C, $\SI{12}{\celsius}$, 1J, $\SI{1}{\joule}$.
\end{document}
```

Here, `\mathsf` (undefined by `hvmaths`) is used: defaulting to computer modern sans serif.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hvmaths}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{OT1}{hvr}{m}{n}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}}
\begin{document}
\verb+\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}+ after preamble OK

123, $123$, \num{123}, $\num{123}$. 12°C, $\SI{12}{\celsius}$, 1J, $\SI{1}{\joule}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is because `siunitx` figures out what to use by checking for the default fonts at the beginning of the document. I imagine that this is so that font packages loaded after `siunitx` are taking proper account of. So I think that `siunitx` is probably overwriting some of your config when you do set up in the preamble whereas you are overwriting some if its config when you do it at the beginning of the document.

Comment: @JosephWright If you have 2 minutes, could you have a look please? thanks.